# Android SDK config issue on IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to set the SDK to my project on IntelliJ and when I select the path to the SDK I get this error.

[image]

I'm using IntelliJ-IDEA as IDE

Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 10:51:28-0300)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: es_CL, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-21-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

javac -version
javac 1.7.0_80

echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Any help?

Comment: Install appropriate Java SDK on your machine. Where do you get stuck with solving this problem?

Comment: which is the appropriate SDK? @Christopher

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Java SE Development Kit (JDK) on your computer in order to compile Java programs (and by extension, Android apps). You can download and install the JDK [from the Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html).

Alternatively, if you're using a Debian-based linux distro (like Ubuntu), you can use OpenJDK:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: Well, it shows you have the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) installed, but not necessarily the JDK. What happens when you type `javac` into a terminal?

Comment: Ok, I'd recommend taking a look at @Mohammed's answer then. `File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK Location` and check your JDK Location is set correctly.

Comment: Trying to do that dosplays the error on the question's image.

Comment: And what if you enable the option to use the embedded JDK? JetBrains has been [bundling their own JDK with IntelliJ](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) recently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136877/discussion-between-rafael-reyes-and-michael-dodd).

Comment: Embedded JDK is "1.8.0_76", I need to use 1.7

Answer (score 0):

You need to define path for JDK in File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK Location. Use this picture as a reference.

For your info, JDK stands for Java Development Kit and can be downloaded from [Download JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

[image: JDK Setup Screen in Project Structure in Android Studio]

Comment: I see that you have installed JRE (Java Runtime Environment), but you have not mentioned about JDK, which I assumed that you have not installed it.

Comment: Run command **where java** in command prompt and see if you are getting similar result to these:

C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe